# Iterate over an Array and search for a Specific Number without Importing anything?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Is there a proper way in Java 7 to iterate with a for-loop over an array and then check for a specific number without importing 'anything'?

I have seen multiple times people pointing to an `ArrayList` or `List` in general, but what if I have to manually iterate over the int array without importing anything than `java.util?`

Comment: Fully-qualify the names of everything you'd otherwise import.

Comment: `for (int e : array) { if (e == specificNumber) { ... } }`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes exactly java.util, gotta edit the main text

Comment: There is a trick answer.  You don't have to use an `import` to use a class.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

You just need a simple for loop, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @return the index of {@code num} in the given array, or `-1` if it's not there
 */
public static int findInArray(int[] arr, int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == num) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is, and you could use a for each loop here:

```
Type[] arr = { /* Values */ };

for (Type val : arr)
{
    if (val == /* Value you want to check */)
        // Or use .equals if the type isn't a primitive type, such as String
    {
        // Do something with val
        break;
    }
}
```

You may even want to implement a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), if your data is large and sorted.